# What is proper time of sahri/suhoor?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

I mean, should we stop eating when we hear azan or at the end of azan? like in Iftar we start eating when we hear azan, so is there is a proper thing of sahri as well?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stop eating directly after the beggining of fajr azan with the first call Allahu Akbar. So basically you can eat from start of maghrib to start of fajr.